# show $\lim_{z \to z_0^-} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z_0^k$ if $z_0$ is a point on circle of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I generalize [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Outline_of_proof) $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to z_0^-} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z_0^k$ if $z_0$ is a point on circle of convergence $R$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z_0^k$ converges and $z \to z_0$ inwards.

Can I consider $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k r^k e^{i k\theta }=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k (z')^k$ where  $b_k = a_k r^k$ use the same steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b_k = a_k z_0^k$, then $a_k z^k = b_k \left(\frac{z}{z_0}\right)^k$.

The result you want then follows if $z/z_0 \to 1^-$.